# excel format option missing on crystal report viewer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports

I used Crystal report 13.0.2000xx on Windows form with Crystal Report Viewer

```
Private Sub CrystalReportViewer1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CrystalReportViewer1.Load

    Dim myConnectionInfo As ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()
    Dim myReport As New ReportDocument()
    myReport.Load("path")
    Dim myTables As Tables = myReport.Database.Tables

    For Each myTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In myTables
        Dim myTableLogonInfo As TableLogOnInfo = myTable.LogOnInfo
        With myConnectionInfo
            .ServerName = "localhost"
            .DatabaseName = "xxxxx"
            .UserID = "xx"
            .Password = "xxxxx"

        End With
    Next
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport
End Sub
```

when I compile and click on export button and choose export to *.xls
there is no Excel format option

my old project use an older version of crystal report it have a excel format option why it's missing in newer version of crystal report

Comment: Do you have Excel installed on the serving machine?

Comment: Yes I have :) maybe it's about the version of dll I have 13.0.2000 but lower version (lower than 10) have Excel format option on export

Comment: Definitely worth a check.